# How to create a project specific startup script for ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I was able to find a lot of documentation on how you can provide configuration files in "IPYTHONDIR" but I would like to have all of my project related files in the project directory itself, that way I my ipython configuration is managed in same git repo and it does not require an extra step when share project with other users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to create a `.ipython` directory in your project directory. You can do this as:

```sh
$ mkdir /path/to/project/.ipython
```

You should then generate default configuration files in this directory as:

```sh
$ ipython profile create my_config_name --ipython-dir /path/to/project/.ipython
```

Now you can edit these default config files as you desire for this project.

Then, we'll need to instruct iPython on where to look to find these config files. To do so we will alter the `IPYTHONDIR` environment variable. This is as simple as:

```sh
$ export IPYTHONDIR=/path/to/project/.ipython
```

With this, iPython will now use the configuration files you've set for this project.

If you're sharing the project with other users you could always put the above export command in a little shell script, say, `set_ipy.sh`, to make things even easier. Just ensure that the script is sourced (`source set_ipy.sh`) and not run as `./set_ipy.sh`, otherwise the `IPYTHONDIR` environment variable will not be altered for the current shell.

Comment: That acutally sounds really good, I could also use autenv to set IPYTHONDIR just for my project. Thanks

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad this helped! I'd not heard of autoenv before, but it sounds like it'd be useful.

Comment: This worked out great!  I added ipython_config.py, startup/README, and a startup file to my project repo, and added `.ipython/**/history.sqlite` to .gitignore, and now I have per-environment command histories and shared project config.